# javascript firstChild, nextSibling read-only

Tags: javascript

I saw that the description of these two property is read-only. what does it mean then, because I make a little test that use `firstChild` like

`$('#one').firstChild.textContent = "ssss"`.

Comment: What do you want exactly ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fine! The firstChild and nextSibling *properties* on the original object are read-only, meaning you cannot change what they refer to. But those properties refer to other nodes, and you can edit the properties of *those* nodes.

This code, however, would not be allowed:

```
$('#one').firstChild = ...
```